# how to know which website is accessing my api in php

Tags: php

How to know which website is accessing my api in php.

Like I can see IP address of that machine using
`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

So how I know the name of that website?

Comment: So you basically want to gather information on the machines accessing your php script?

Comment: @Sood you do realize that you can host multiple website on a single machine with a single IP address, don't you ?

Comment: i don't want to store the infomation . for authentication method i require the website name becouse i want to give access to only selected website

Comment: @Teneff that's why i want the website address like www.example.com is try to acces ur code

Answer (score 3):

### [`REMOTE_HOST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

> The Host name from which the user is viewing the current page. The reverse dns lookup is based off the REMOTE_ADDR of the user.

**Note:** Your web server must be configured to create this variable. For example in Apache you'll need *`HostnameLookups On`* inside *httpd.conf* for it to exist. See also [`gethostbyaddr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php).

That is as far as you can succeed.

---

I'd include above comment from @Teneff *you do realize that you can host multiple website on a single machine with a single IP address*

Comment: ur ans gives me just machine name i want website address

Comment: **That is as far as you can succeed.** Was mentioned for a reason. Also, I'd include above comment from @Teneff *you do realize that you can host multiple website on a single machine with a single IP address*

Comment: So tat mean we can't find the website address ....r8t?

Comment: Maybe you can use `curl` or `wget` requests and fetch the index page. Ofcourse, it'll only work and fetch the title from the IP addresses. @Sood

Answer (score 0):

There is a function [gethostbyname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) which I think would do the job for you if the workflow is like this:

1. The user configures API credentials
2. Adds domain name where the requests will be made from
3. Upon authentication you check whether the result from `gethostbyname( $api_client['domain'] )` is equal to `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

and this way even if the client address has been changed it will be resolved.